# Como interpretar teste de Johansen no R?

Tags: r

[image: Como interpretar teste de Johansen no R]

Olá. Gostaria de saber como interpretar o teste de Johansen para saber se existe ou não cointegração entre as séries envolvidas no modelo. Grato.

Comment: Após uma pesquisa no Google, seguem alguns links que podem ajudar [link1](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Johansen-Test-for-Cointegrating-Time-Series-Analysis-in-R), [link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186208/johansen-test-for-cointegration), [link3](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18836/interpretation-of-johansen-cointegration-test-in-r) e [link4](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/how-to-interpret-results-of-johansen-test)

Comment: Obrigado, Rafael.

Comment: A melhor hipotese neste caso r <=4, visto que o teste de hipotese testa a hipotese nula, logo como o valor de teste  de matriz que vc procura deve ser formando por 4 variáveis para ter estacionariedade. os valores de lambda são o valores de correção de erro más quanto a isso n tenho toal certeza.